# Order versions as numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with file-names and version with subversion of files separated by `.`.

```
FNAME, VERSION 
A      0.0.10
B      10.12.412

-- For example
create table file_versions as 
select chr(mod(level,13)+65) as fname
     , decode(mod(level,99),0, '0',
          mod(level,10)||'.'||mod(level,500)||'.'||mod(level,14)
       )
      as version 
  from dual connect by level < 1001;
```

I'd like to order files by version, but use versions as numbers

```
select fname, version from file_versions 
 order by fname, version 

FNAME, VERSION 
A      0.0.10
A      0.0.6
...
```

I'd like don't think about subversion level(there may be one number (0) or more(1.23.14123)). How should I write order by statement ?

I may write something like:

```
select fname, version from file_versions 
 order by fname
        , to_number(substr(version, 1, instr(version, '.',1,1)-1))
        , to_number(substr(version, instr(version, '.',1,1)+1, instr(version, '.',1,2)-instr(version, '.',1,1)-1))
        , to_number(substr(version, instr(version, '.',1,2)+1))
```

But its not so good and will not work if one digit was added to the version string (e.g. 0.0.0.123). Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use two regexp first for enhance you group to add 5 zeros to any group. And another one to take last 5 digits from each group. And you get constant length rows and be able to sort it as chars.

```
with s(txt) as (select '1' from dual 
             union all 
            select '1.12' from dual 
             union all 
            select '1.12.410' from dual 
             union all 
            select rpad('1.12.410',401,'.03') from dual 
             union all 
            select rpad('1.12.410',401,'.03')||'.01' from dual 
             union all 
            select rpad('1.12.410',401,'.03')||'.02' from dual               
) 
select txt,regexp_replace(regexp_replace(txt, '(\d+)','00000\1'),'\d+ (\d{5})','\1') from s 
order by regexp_replace(regexp_replace(txt, '(\d+)','00000\1'),'\d+(\d{5})','\1')
```

It will work up to 99999 version or subversion.

Comment: there is odd space in '\d+ (\d{5})'

Answer (score 3):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
order by fname,
         cast(regexp_substr(version, '[^.]+', 1, 1) as number),
         cast(regexp_substr(version, '[^.]+', 1, 2) as number),
         cast(regexp_substr(version, '[^.]+', 1, 3) as number)
```

Comment: Thank you. It will work fine with 3 sublevel. But what about additional  levels of subversion?

Comment: Simply add them in the same way. Unless you have more than 1000 levels (which I doubt) it will work.

Comment: @Michael Piankov: Above sort order workls for *up to* 3 levels. So add lines to have it work for up to n levels instead.

Comment: It means 2 ways. 1) write a lot of `..cast(regexp_substr(version, '[^.]+', 1, 100) as number),...` 2) rewrite query any time. Both ways are not so good imho.

Comment: @Michael Piankov: We are talking of version numbers, right? It should be possible to settle for a maximum number of levels, say 10 for instance.

Answer (score 1):

More for fun than as a serious suggestion, here's an alternative to parsing the string -- treating the version numbers as inet addresses.

Trickier when you have three levels in your version, but trivial for four levels:

Starting with the idea of:

```
select a.i::varchar
from (select '192.168.100.128'::inet i union 
      select '22.168.100.128'::inet) a 
order by 1;

        i          
--------------------
 192.168.100.128/32
 22.168.100.128/32
(2 rows)
```

So for three-level versions you can:

```
with
  versions as (
    select '1.12.1' v union 
    select '1.3.100'),
  inets as (
    select (v||'.0')::inet i
    from   versions)
select substr(i::varchar,1,length(i::varchar)-5)
from inets
order by i;

 substr  
---------
 1.3.100
 1.12.1
(2 rows)
```

Maybe everyone should have four level versions ...